# Asked question with wrong account, deleted, and now can't repost

Tags: support, duplicates, deleted-questions

I posted a question with the wrong account by mistake (because of an SE bug, actually, but that's another matter) and immediately deleted it. Now I want to post it as a guest but I can't, since it says it's a duplicate of the one I posted before (even though it's deleted!).

Is there a way to post the question?

Comment: Can you give a little more info?